# Probability of a random number being smaller than another random number

Tags: probability

As title implies, can anyone help me with this problem? Let's say we define an array $A\langle 1,\cdots,n \rangle$ where each element is random (real) and distinct. Let $\mathtt{temp} = A\langle1\rangle$.

> *for* $j=2$ *to* $n$:
>
> $\hspace{2em}$ if $A\langle j \rangle < \mathtt{temp}$
>
> $\hspace{4em}$ $A\langle j \rangle = \mathtt{temp}$

What would be the probability of $A\langle j \rangle < \mathtt{temp}$ ?

Comment: I guess 1/2 if negatives are allowed. If negatives are not allowed, then 0. Because for any positive number a, there are only finitely many smaller positives but infinitely many larger positives.

Comment: If they are independent and sampled from the same continuous distribution (such as the uniform distribution on $[0,1]$), then the probability for $A\langle j \rangle < A\langle 1 \rangle$ is $1/2$ for ech $j\geq 2$ by symmetry.